# QEMU VM network bridge in WLAN/Wifi

Tags: networking, server, virtualization, qemu, network-bridge

Host (Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS) is connected through WLAN/Wifi.

My goal:

- QEMU VM (Linux Kernel created with buildroot) has it's own local IP address, host can reach VM through this IP address
- it doesn't matter, if the VM has internet or is reachable from somewhere else than the host
- host has a separate IP address, therefore NAT is unsuitable

Just creating a bridge using network manager is not suitable, because I only have WLAN:

> Note that a bridge cannot be established over Wi-Fi networks operating
> in Ad-Hoc or Infrastructure modes. This is due to the IEEE 802.11
> standard that specifies the use of 3-address frames in Wi-Fi for the
> efficient use of airtime.

[Source](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/ch-configure_network_bridging)

This tutorial is maybe my solution, but it is written for Gentoo.
https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/QEMU/Bridge_with_Wifi_Routing

Is there a similar ubuntu config file "etc/conf.d/net"? Is it possible, to apply this tutorial on ubuntu?